# Generate a tree with recursive array combining data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have to generate a tree from two MySQL tables in PHP and print it with HTML. My main problem is that I've two tables where to get data. One table is **pages** and other **translations** because I've 3 languages in the website and all the translations remains on the **translations** table.

The schema of this tables is:

**pages**

```
id INT
id_user INT
id_parent INT
order INT
template INT
image VARCHAR
flag_active INT
flag_extra INT
edited INT
created INT
```

**translations**

```
id INT
id_user INT
locale VARCHAR
module VARCHAR
pk INT
label VARCHAR
value TEXT
edited INT
```

When I add a page I the values `title, slug and text` of pages (not on the schema, because there are depending of the locale) into the translations:

```
INSERT INTO pages (id_user, template, image, flag_active, flag_extra, edited, created)
VALUES (1, 0, 'test.jpg', 1, 1, 12345, 12345)

<!-- the pages.id is 4, for example, for next insert: -->

INSERT INTO translations (id_user, locale, module, pk, label, value, edited)
VALUES (1, 'en', 'pages', 4, 'title', 'This is the title in English', 12345)

INSERT INTO translations (id_user, locale, module, pk, label, value, edited)
VALUES (1, 'en', 'pages', 4, 'slug', 'this-is-the-title-in-english', 12345)

INSERT INTO translations (id_user, locale, module, pk, label, value, edited)
VALUES (1, 'en', 'pages', 4, 'text', 'This is the text in English', 12345)

INSERT INTO translations (id_user, locale, module, pk, label, value, edited)
VALUES (1, 'es', 'pages', 4, 'title', 'Este es el titulo en Español', 12345)

INSERT INTO translations (id_user, locale, module, pk, label, value, edited)
VALUES (1, 'es', 'pages', 4, 'slug', 'este-es-el-titulo-en-espanol', 12345)

INSERT INTO translations (id_user, locale, module, pk, label, value, edited)
VALUES (1, 'es', 'pages', 4, 'text', 'Este es el contenido en Español', 12345)
```

And then when I've to access to a page in a certain language, in PHP first I select the page from the table `pages` and then look in `translations` for: `WHERE module='pages' AND pk='4' AND locale='en'` and I get all the information I need from the page and the translated text values.

I've explained how it works my translations system. Now I've a problem in the backend (and frontend) because **I need to build a tree from this pages in one language**. My idea is to go throw a recursive array but I don't know how to merge the data because I think this will be a PHP thing and not a MySQL one.

I haven't build the tree function and I think I need to tree functions because:

1. I need to generate and array from the MySQL query/ies, combining the page data and the translation.
2. I need to generate a `<ol />` list in HTML with the nested tree.

For the first first tree array, the MySQL one, *I need to make a MySQL for EACH entry*? Or this can be done with only one MySQL query? Code example, not tested and written directly:

```
function mysql_tree($parent_id = 0)
{
    $return = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id_parent=$parent_id";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
    {
        $i = 0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $return[$i] = array(
                'id' => $row["id"];
                //etc
            );

            // Time to merge the data for each page from translations????

            $return[$i]["childs"] = mysql_tree($row["id"]);

            $i++;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

For the second tree function I suppose that something similar to the MySQL?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:** example of nested list requested by Vincent

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 4
        [id_user] => 1
        [id_parent] => 0
        [order] => 0
        [template] => 1
        [image] => NULL
        [flag_active] => 1
        [flag_extra] => 0
        [edited] => 12345
        [created] => 12345
        [title] => This is the title in English
        [slug] => this-is-the-slug-in-english
        [childs] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [id] => 5
                [id_user] => 1
                [id_parent] => 4
                [order] => 0
                [template] => 1
                [image] => NULL
                [flag_active] => 1
                [flag_extra] => 0
                [edited] => 12345
                [created] => 12345
                [title] => This is the title in English 2
                [slug] => this-is-the-slug-in-english-2
                [childs] => NULL
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And the HTML tree:

```
<ol>
    <li class="id_4"><a href="/pages/this-is-the-slug-in-english">This is the title in English</a>
        <ol>
            <li class="id_5"><a href="/pages/this-is-the-slug-in-english-2">This is the title in English 2</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @Tomalak: haha I tried to explain all the whole thing because people usually says that I don't describe and answer well. Resuming: I've two tables for a nested tree, that can not be joined in MySQL because it uses another procedure for storing languages, and I want to know how to do a generate the tree with the less MySQL queries possible.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the resulting nested list will look like? Do you just want the page titles to be displayed and indent all children under each page title?

Comment: @Vincent: updated. The array was manually wrote so can be some errors but you get the idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by using the needed MySQL queries. I post the code because can be useful for someother user. I'm using CodeIgniter, but it will work with a normal mysql_query().

PS: Note that I'm using Spanish names, btw it's easy to understand.

```
public function tree($id_padre = 0, $locale = null)
{
    $return = array();

    if(false == is_numeric($id_padre))
        return $return;

    if(null == $locale)
        return $return;

    $query = $this->db->where("id_padre", $id_padre)->get("paginas");

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $i = 0;

        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $translation = (array) $this->get($row["id"], $locale); // This returns the "title", "slug" and "text" from the translations tables

            $data["id"] = $row["id"];
            $data["id_padre"] = $row["id_padre"];
            $data["orden"] = $row["orden"];

            $data = array_merge($data, $translation);

            $data["childs"] = $this->tree($row["id"], $locale);

            $return[$i] = $data;

            unset($data);

            $i++;
        }

        return $return;

    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

And the HTML tree:

```
function backend_tree($array = null, $class = null)
{
    if(null == $array)
        return false;

    $return = '<ol';

    if(null != $class)
        $return .= ' class="'.$class.'"';

    $return .= '>';

    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        $return .= '<li id="id-'.$item["id"].'"><div>'.$item["titulo"];
        $return .= '<div class="edit">'.anchor("/admin/carta/edit/".$item["id"], " ", array("class" => "sortableEdit")).' '.anchor("/admin/carta/delete/".$item["id"], " ", array("class" => "sortableDelete")).'</div>';
        $return .= '</div>';
        $return .= backend_tree($item["childs"]);
        $return .= '</li>';
    }

    $return .= '</ol>';

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less queries - mean JOIN :-)

Idea - join it with language - so you get 3 rows per page , and process it into associated array :-) ( eg. $result[$row["id"]]['title'] = $row['title']; )